# Why I can't import this module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everything is obvious as the below image and the codes followed it :
I want to import a module that phycially there is in the `D:\pyusb-1.0.0a2\usb`, but I receive errors!

[image]

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('d:\pyusb-1.0.0a2\usb')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \uXXXX escape
>>> sys.path.append('d:/pyusb-1.0.0a2/usb')
>>> from usb import core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import core
ImportError: No module named 'usb'

>>> import core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import core
  File "d:/pyusb-1.0.0a2/usb\core.py", line 44, in <module>
    import usb.util as util
ImportError: No module named 'usb'

>>> import usb.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import usb.core
ImportError: No module named 'usb'
>>>
```

Comment: try `sys.path.append('d:\\pyusb-1.0.0a2\\usb')`

Comment: @klasske: no, that's not the issue. The OP (and you) misunderstood how the `sys.path` search path works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was looking at the first error, which was caused by the escaped `\u`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append `d:/pyusb-1.0.0a2/` to your Python path, and **not** `d:/pyusb-1.0.0a2/usb/`.

As you can see when trying to import `core` the error is no longer that *your* import failed, but that the `usb.core` module did not manage to import `usb.util` since there's no `usb` module available in your Python path, only modules *inside* `usb`, such as `core` or `util`.

Comment: Yes, but remove `usb` from the path.

Comment: @TheGoodUser: no, you did not. You appended the path *plus `usb`*. Remove the package name.